# Use condition one time for run multiple command line

Tags: powershell

I am still newbie with powershell, i still learning. i want to add condition for each command, this is how i currently doing. i am looking is to use the condition only one time which will use for each command line. any help or guidance will be appreciate. sorry for my bad English.

```
If ((Get-ChildItem -Force "C:\Document") -eq $Null) {
 Move-Item -Path "C:\new1\*" -Destination "C:\Document_test" -Force -Verbose;
}
If ((Get-ChildItem -Force "C:\Document") -eq $Null) {
Move-Item -Path "C:\new2\*" -Destination "C:\Document_test" -Force -Verbose;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it is best practice to place the `$null` on the left of the `-eq`: [PossibleIncorrectComparisonWithNull](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/master/RuleDocumentation/PossibleIncorrectComparisonWithNull.md)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion and the link

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? It looks like you're checking a folder is empty and then putting some stuff in it, then checking if it's empty again (which it possibly won't be because you just put stuff in it) before adding some more stuff to it?

Another tip is `"C:\new[12]*"` is equivalent to both `C:\new1*` and `C:\new2*`

Comment: sorry my mistake. post has been modified. yes if folder is empty run move command. i want to use the check folder empty use that condition for all command but use it only once so that script looks simple.

Comment: Instead of testing for $null, I would do `if (@(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Document" -Force).Count -eq 0) { <# folder is empty #> }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of an `if` statement is just a *list* of statements, you can put as many `Move-Item` calls into it as you want:

```
if (-not(Get-ChildItem -Force "C:\Document")) {
  Move-Item -Path "C:\new1\*" -Destination "C:\Document_test" -Force -Verbose
  Move-Item -Path "C:\new2\*" -Destination "C:\Document_test" -Force -Verbose
}
```

If you have a variable (or just *large*) number of source folders to move, use a `foreach` loop over the paths:

```
if (-not(Get-ChildItem -Force "C:\Document")) {
  foreach($path in "C:\new1\*", "C:\new2\*"){
    Move-Item -Path $path -Destination "C:\Document_test" -Force -Verbose
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks the solution which i asked you gave it but i did not able to describe my problem properly. basically i want to run if folder is empty run first command. once command run done burn it. and then again check the folder if empty run the second command (or after burn/remove it become first command) probably not possible